# How to create sort of DB View in Django (derived models without any db table)

Tags: django, python-3.x, model

This is my `Story` class in models.py:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content if len(self.content) <= 8 else self.content[:8]+"..."
    master = models.ForeignKey(User)
    story_book = models.ForeignKey(Story_book)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    STORY_TYPES = (
        ('bf', 'before commited'),
        ('cm', 'commited'),
        ('dl', 'deleted'),
    )
    Story_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STORY_TYPES, default='bf')
    handled_date = models.DateTimeField('date handled', null=True)
```

I want make 3 classes that show elements of Storys:

- One model with `bf` type only
- ... one with `cm` type only
- ... and the last one with `dl` type only

I want all the data stored in the `Story`database table, but handling different models. How can I do that?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do seems to be [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), with a custom manager :

```
class Story(models.Model):
    """ Base model, will be represented in database """
    master = models.ForeignKey(User)
    [...]
    Story_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STORY_TYPES, default='bf')


class StoryManager(models.Manager):
    """ Manager used for proxies, to automatically filter by type """
    def __init__(self, story_type=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoryManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.story_type = story_type

   def get_queryset(self):
        return super(StoryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(Story_type=self.story_type)


class BeforeCommitedStory(Story):
    """ Each proxy take the custom manager with the revelant type """
    objects = StoryManager('bf')
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class CommitedStory(Story):
    objects = StoryManager('cm')
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class DeletedStory(Story):
    objects = StoryManager('dl')
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

You should obtain the following behaviour:

```
Story.objects.create(..., type="bf") # ID 1
Story.objects.create(..., type="bf")  
Story.objects.create(..., type="cm")
Story.objects.create(..., type="dl")

Story.objects.all() # [ID 1, ID 2, ID 3, ID 4]
BeforeCommitedStory.objects.all() # [ID 1, ID 2]
CommitedStory.objects.all() # [ID 3]
DeletedStory.objects.all() # [ID 4]
```